# Can Lync 2010 and Communicator 2007 (w/ or w/o R2) client be installed on the same machine

Tags: lync-2010, office-communicator

Can both clients be installed and used at the same time ?

The purpose of using both is based needs to develop for Lync 2010 while still using Communicator 2007 in a corporate environment.  Or would a developer be forced to have two different machines/VMs/boot environments ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - you can't run both side-by-side. Installing Lync will uninstall Communicator.

However, you can use a [registry hack](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ocsclients/thread/1743fca3-d2aa-460d-85dc-003b2572f0c8) (unsupported, unfortunately) to enable your copy of Lync to run against your OCS infrastructure. This works for R2, not 100% sure about R1.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator]"DisableServerCheck"=dword:00000001
```

If you're serious about Lync development, the best solution is to build a server environment specifically for developing against.

Comment: The same registry hack can be activated for the Lync 2013 Client Preview, but at a different registry path: 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\lync] "DisableServerCheck"=dword:00000001

Comment: If you install the 32 bit version of Lync on a 64 bit Windows, try [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\lync]